# Remove img tag from Html.Raw in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, replace, substring

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC4 web application which has a News section that displays a list of News articles. The list shows the News Headline for each article and then prints out the first 400 characters of the News text as this is only a summary page. When the user clicks the News headline, they then get to see the News article in full.

To add a News article to the site, I use FCKEditor as a rich text editor which also allows the user to upload an image to accompany the text. When I print out the first 400 characters of each News article I do so like this

```
@Html.Raw(news.newsText.Substring(0, 400))
```

This works fine whenever there is no image tag inside the first 400 characters, however, if the user adds an image to their text which is in the first 400 characters, the image is shown in the News summary and this makes it look messy.

Rather, if there is an image tag inside the first 400 characters, I would prefer not to show it, and instead, just display text.

I was wondering if this is possible?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression to remove all `<img>` tags from HTML and then Take 400 characters from it.

You can create you own Extension Method for this as below:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string SkipImgTags(this string html, int length)
    {
       string strWithoutImgTags = Regex.Replace( html, @"(<img\/?[^>]+>)", @"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );

        return strWithoutImgTags.Substring(strWithoutImgTags.Length - length);
    }
}
```

And then , in your code, you can call this as below:

```
@Html.Raw(news.newsText.SkipImgTags(400))
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you get to the razor you can strip them in the controller with code like this.

```
var news = news.newsText.Substring(0, 400);
news = Regex.Replace(news, @"<img\s[^>]*>(?:\s*?</img>)?", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

However, I would suggest using something like the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for tasks such as these.